# Account Still getting merged

Tags: support, status-completed, login, user-accounts

My account is still getting merged with my brother's account even though my suspension period is over.

This happens even if I try using a different system with different IP address.

I cleared all logins from that account from `my login`. How can I resolve this?

Comment: try removing all cookies from both computers - this should force you to login in again without remembering previous login details.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your brother's account? Thanks.

Comment: @AnnaLear it was merged in to this one. Does not exist anymore. Uid from 2nd account was 52514.

Comment: @BrunoPereira Oy, this is why I shouldn't do this late at night. =) Thanks for the id.

Comment: @AnnaLear thank you for the assistance! ;)

Answer (score 8):

We've fixed this, or so I'm told. :) You should be able to log in again without getting auto-merged into your sibling's account.

Answer (score 3):

You have removed the email account from the addresses in your login but Gmail still considers the site as authorized to access your Gmail data and log you in in Ask Ubuntu.

Go to your brother's *Gmail account* > *Account Settings*, look for *Security* > *Application and sites authorization*, click **Edit**. From the list of authorized sites look for *askubuntu.com* and click **Remove Access Authorization**.

I am assuming that you have used Gmail to login to Stack Exchange with his account, if you use another service this should be similar.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that there are no mail addresses in common between the two accounts, neither in the email field nor in the OpenIDs. There is some semi-automatic or automatic merging happening with that.

Also make sure not to log in on top of each other. Always log yourself out before your brother logs in. That can also trigger a merge.

Comment: i already tired all this thing nothing helps